# got error message when use getElementsByTagName in js

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Blah</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementsByTagName("a").onclick(function () {
         alert('Hello!');

      });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Question:

In chrome->console, it shows:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'onclick'

So what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: add array index. [0] in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)** returns a collection so you need to do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onclick = function () {
         alert('Hello!');

      };
```

Note 0 will cause first anchor to be considered so use the index appropriately to select the one that is required (if you have more than one anchor tags). **Also note the syntax of onclick. it is a property not a method. so you need to use assignment operator `=` to assign the event handler reference**

Answer (score 0):

The method returns a colection ([HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)), and it doesn't have an `onclick` method.

As you have only one element, you can just use the first item from the collection:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onclick(function () {
  alert('Hello!');
});
```